# Проблема с виджетом Yii2

Tags: yii2, inputmask

Использую маску для поля ввода номера телефона

```
$form->field($model, 'phone')->textInput(['value'=>$info['phone']])->widget(\yii\widgets\MaskedInput::className(), ['mask' => '+7 (999)-999-9999']);
```

Все хорошо работает, но после сохранения не выводит значение, хотя оно не пустое

```
textInput(['value'=>$info['phone']])
```

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: А без маски выводит?

Comment: без маски показывает

Answer (score 1):

Вы задаете не поддерживаемый формат маски. Читайте [здесь](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-widgets-maskedinput.html).

Поддерживаемые значения:

- a: символы алфавита (A-Z, a-z)
- 9: цифры (0-9)
- *: и цифры и числа (A-Z, a-z, 0-9)
- [ и ]: опциональный маркер.

В вашем случии `+7` я бы вывле как текст или label перед input-ом.